# How do international rankings influence national policy?

Tags: indicators, policy

> **Please note:** This question probably has one answer per country, nonetheless I believe it interesting as a comparative question.

Jakobi and Lamping argue in [Journal of political science (in German)](http://www.zpol.nomos.de/fileadmin/zpol/doc/Aufsatz_ZPol_11_03.pdf) that:

> Rankings seem to be ubiquitous and also International Organizations use them as policy-instruments to influence national policies. Especially a rather new type of rankings based on complex indicators do have the potential to gain impact on national policies. Yet, an analysis of the policy processes around the first PISA study and the World Health Report 2000 in Germany show that specific aspects of national policy processes like actors and their interests or the point of time in election cycles and policy reform cycles mainly influence the reaction to an international ranking. Characteristics of rankings can make a difference but are subsequent to those aspects of the national policy process. Hence, we suggest to understand rankings analytically rather as external interferences in national discourses than as shocks.

Now this is an analysis of german policy, as I believe this is a question that may yield different answers for different countries I was wondering if that question has also been researched in the context of maybe the G20-countries?

Comment: Are you asking about **actual tangible** policy influence as a direct cause, or political arguments made on the basis of rankings, without necessarily proof that the ranking was fully causative of the argument made to support the policy?

Comment: I would prefer actual tangible proof, but I know that this is near to impossible in a political context, thus I would be happy with studies on political arguments of the government…

Answer (score -1):

> *How do international rankings influence national policy?*

There is an influence whereby the United States has used PISA as a reference to change its education policy. The US has also used other indicators to influence the policies of other countries.

Beyond those, both PISA and OECD indicators influenced education policies in Spain and Italy.

Mostly, the influence on education is toward increased funding and testing.

(I did not look at the influences on health care as suggested by the inclusion of *World Health Report 2000* in the quote.)

---

This first reference is, perhaps, not what you are looking for since it involves a G20 country influencing those that are – well – not.

[Indicators as Social Pressure in International Relations](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/13578027/157696/kelley_and_simmons_ajps.pdf;jsessionid=B5FA24234B91DD0C3E90D6FCED0DCD42?sequence=1)

> Abstract
>
> The ability to monitor state behavior has become a critical tool of international governance. Systematic monitoring allows for the creation of numerical indicators that can be used to rank, compare and essentially censure states. This article argues that the ability to disseminate such numerical indicators widely and instantly constitutes an exercise of social power, with the potential to change important policy outputs. It explores this argument in the context of the United States’ efforts to combat trafficking in persons and find evidence that monitoring has important effects: countries are more likely to criminalize human trafficking when they are included in the US annual Trafficking in Persons Report, while countries that are placed on a “watch list” are also more likely to criminalize. These findings have broad implications for international governance and the exercise of soft power in the global information age.

Mostly, through my years of following the activities of the US Congress, the policy influences that come to mind involve education and technology. The concerns are expressed generally as "the United States is falling behind" other countries. For example,

- [No Child Left Behind Act of 2001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/no_child_left_behind_act_of_2001)

> NCLB was designed to address the concern that the American education system was lagging behind its international competitors by holding schools responsible for boosting student performance through mandated standardized tests and minimum performance benchmarks.

- [Science, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics (STEM) Education: Background, Federal Policy, and Legislative Action](https://sgp.fas.org/crs/misc/RL33434.pdf#page=2)

> There is growing concern that the United States is not preparing a sufficient number of students, teachers, and practitioners in the areas of science, technology, engineering, and mathematics (STEM). A large majority of secondary school students fail to reach proficiency in math and science, and many are taught by teachers lacking adequate subject matter knowledge.
>
> When compared to other nations, the math and science achievement of U.S. pupils and the rate of STEM degree attainment appear inconsistent with a nation considered the world leader in scientific innovation. In a recent international assessment of 15-year-old students, the U.S. ranked 28th in math literacy and 24th in science literacy. Moreover, the U.S. ranks 20th among all nations in the proportion of 24-year-olds who earn degrees in natural science or engineering.

(The linked CRS Report refers to the 2003 Program for International Student Assessment (PISA) — the second PISA study.)

- And, "... concerns remain about persistent academic achievement gaps between various demographic groups, STEM teacher quality, the rankings of U.S. students on international STEM assessments, foreign student enrollments and increased education attainment in other countries, ...". [Source](https://sgp.fas.org/crs/misc/R42642.pdf#page=2)

Though such concerns are expressed for another G20 country (and guest), as well.

[Global Influences on National Definitions of Quality Education: examples from Spain and Italy](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.2304/pfie.2014.12.6.769)

> ABSTRACT There is increasing attention worldwide to advancing quality education. Beyond a rhetorical aim, many international organizations and national education systems have articulated a commitment to promoting measures of quality education through the development of educational indicators. This article broadly explores the global influences on national definitions and measures of quality education through examining select educational issues in Spain and Italy. Through an examination of select educational issues in these two illustrative national examples, there appears to be a connection between the ways in which educational quality indicators are used and defined at the national and international level. These examples provide insight into how the Organisation for Economic and Co-operation and Development (OECD) influences educational policy developments in quality education within the national space, particularly through its own Education at a Glance indicators and Programme for International Student Assessment (PISA). The authors argue that by including key international indicators of quality at the national level, the OECD wields considerable influence in national education policy spaces, and, furthermore, narrows what it means to develop quality education.

Not all research into the use of indicators for national educational policies is necessarily positive.

[An Examination of the Influence of International Large Scale Assessments and Global Learning Metrics on National School Reform Policies](https://education.asu.edu/sites/default/files/casge_working_papers_2_updated.pdf)

> Our review of the literature confirms that ILSAs/GLMs, with their multiple and ambiguous uses, increasingly function as *solutions in search for the right problem* (see Lewis, 2016) – that is, they appear to be used by governments as tools to legitimate existing or new educational reforms. Our survey results pointed to a growing perception among researchers, policymakers, educators, and other stakeholders that ILSAs/GLMs are having an effect on national educational policies, with over one-third (38%) of all survey respondents stating that ILSAs/GLMs were generally misused in national policy contexts. However, while the ILSA/GLM literature indicates that ILSAs/GLMs are having some influence (Breakspear, 2012), there is little evidence that any positive or negative causal relationship exists between ILSA/GLM participation and the implementation of education reforms (Baird et al., 2016; Rutkowski & Delandshere, 2016). Consistent with these findings, our survey respondents were divided over whether, based on their professional and personal experiences, ILSAs/GLMs were positive contributors or hindrances to national education reform efforts.